# WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication is delayed on real device?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, watchkit, apple-watch

I've been tracking this bug for days and finally realized the issue is that there is an actual delay with `WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication`. I am not referring to the callback in the Apple Watch, but the `AppDelegate` event in the iPhone.

Here's what I'm doing in the Apple Watch:

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
  var userInfo = [
    "test": 123
  ]

  WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(userInfo, reply: nil)
}
```

Then in the iPhone, I'm doing this in `AppDelegate`:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {
  let test = userInfo["test"]
  // Do something
}
```

The problem is when I call `WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication`, there is a 2 or 3 second delay before the `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest` event is triggered in the iPhone. This is problematic if the user performs an action on their watch really quickly and puts down their arm right after. I can't assume the user is going to hold up their arm for 3 seconds until the watch sends the command.

Here's the catch: if the user wakes up the watch, the command still doesn't get sent to the iPhone.. UNTIL the user opens up the original app that sent the `WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication`. I don't think any of this would be a problem without this catch, the command should be queued until the watch is awakened, not awakened AND reopen the app.

Any workaround that can be done for this? I plan on logging this as a bug, but wanted to see if anyone has any thoughts or experience with this?

Comment: You feel like there is a delay. Have you verified/measured the delay with logging?

Comment: Need more info/code to really help. Perhaps you should implement the reply block so you can see if an error is being returned.

Comment: The command that gets sent actually does happen on the iPhone and the update refreshes the screen, so it doesn't seem like there is an error. You'll have to bare with me a bit because I can't debug these issues since this only happens on the real device and not the simulator, which makes tracking this much harder. There's no way make the watch simulator sleep or go to the home unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Have you tried running the handleWatchKitExtensionRequest code in a background task?